# Prevent varnish from caching page when backend explicitly sets Cache-Control: no-cache?

Tags: cache, varnish, http-headers

There are times when certain pages need to avoid being cached, and they all have the following response header set by the backend:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

Varnish, however, happily caches these pages nonetheless. Is there something I can add to the config to prevent this? I'm guessing it's something that should go into `vcl_deliver` or `vcl_fetch` subroutines, [but the documentation isn't very helpful](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html) (to me anyway).

Basically looking for something [like this](https://www.section.io/blog/Varnish-Caching-Pages-and-ignoring-Cache-control-no-cache-header/) but in reverse - should check headers on the response.

Varnish is version 3.0 (no, can't upgrade right now)

---

Relevant config:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Use-Cache && beresp.status != 500) {
        set beresp.ttl = 24h;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if(!resp.http.X-Cache) {
        if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = resp.http.X-Cache + ", HIT";
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = resp.http.X-Cache + ", MISS";
        }
    }
    set resp.http.X-Flavour = req.http.X-Flavour;
    return (deliver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Varnish should be honoring the `Cache-Control` header.

The most likely cause is the `return (deliver)` in your `vcl_fetch` which will bypass the default handling that Varnish has, which is what will generally apply the `Cache-Control` settings and mark the content as not cacheable.

So I would recommend you remove that from the bottom of `vcl_fetch`.

Comment: I added the `vcl_fetch` and `vcl_deliver` configuration to the post. I didn't write it so not sure how different it is from the default behavior. Please take a look.